# Magento 1.7.0.2 Small Bug need to fix

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, custom-options

I am using custom option for image uploading . when product ordered and i gets downloadable link in order.
But if you **enable** System -> Cofiguration -> Web -> Url options -> Add store code to urls than  not able to download that image in order.its redirect me on dashboard.

Is there any permanent solution for it ? or every time when i want to download that image i need to disable this option .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the following function in

> app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php

to below:

From

```
protected function _getOptionDownloadUrl($route, $params)
{

   return Mage::getUrl($route, $params);
}
```

To

```
protected function _getOptionDownloadUrl($route, $params)
{
    $websites = Mage::app()->getWebsites();
    $code = $websites[1]->getDefaultStore()->getCode();
    $params['_store'] = $code;

    return Mage::getUrl($route, $params);
}
```

Comment: Please specify the product required option(s). I am unable to upload  image.

Comment: Have you any idea why this stuff happen i override this class and i am unable to upload image and getting error " 
Please specify the product required option(s)"

Comment: its not work in my project otherwise its work very weell

Comment: Adding this code but upload image not downloading in order view.Click on the image link its give  404 error...and also disable “Add Store Code to Urls” in System -> Configuration -> General -> Web but images are not downloading